# How to return 1 String in case there are multiple IF statements

Tags: java, string, if-statement, return-value

How can I return 1 value, in case I have some IF statements?

For example, when I choose Shopify, it calls a new method that allows me to type into console some need credentials and then append all typied data into 1 String and return that String(test) to Main class.
In case, I choose Bigcommerce, it calls pretty much the same method and append all needed credentials for Biggcomerce into 1 String(test2) as well. But in this case public String credentailsCollector() should return test2.

How can I do that? Thanks.

```
public class CartCredentialsCollector {
//it should return something like this: 
//store_url=https://test.myshopify.com&apiKey=myapikey&apiPassword=myapipassword

public String credentailsCollector() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Do you want to connect a new shopping cart ('yes'/'no')");
    String newConnection = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if (newConnection.equals("no")) {
        bufferedReader.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Specify your shopping cart. It works with Shopify and Bigcommerce only");
        String newShoppingCart = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (newShoppingCart.equals("Shopify")) {
            ShopifyCredentialsHandler sch = new ShopifyCredentialsHandler();
            String test = sch.shopifyCredentialsHandler();
        }
        else if (newShoppingCart.equals("Bigcommerce")) {
        BigcommerceCredentialsHandler bch = new BigcommerceCredentialsHandler();
        String test2 = bch.bigcommerceCredentialsHandler()
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("This method works with Shopify and Bigcommerce. Try to connect a Shopify or Bigcommerce store.");
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
    // Here I need to return test (in case I choose "Shopify") or test2 (in case I choose "Bigcommerce"). How can I do that?
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have multiple return statements throughout your method.

Comment: Some alternatives: (1) return the string at the point where you invoke the chosen method; (2) declare String `test` at the outermost scope of the method, and set that *same* variable to your method result, whichever method it is you call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a method scope String variable and set the value of that instead of two different String variables. Something like this:

```
public class CartCredentialsCollector {
//it should return something like this: 
//store_url=https://test.myshopify.com&apiKey=myapikey&apiPassword=myapipassword

public String credentailsCollector() throws IOException {
    String test = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Do you want to connect a new shopping cart ('yes'/'no')");
    String newConnection = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if (newConnection.equals("no")) {
        bufferedReader.close();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Specify your shopping cart. It works with Shopify and Bigcommerce only");
        String newShoppingCart = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (newShoppingCart.equals("Shopify")) {
            ShopifyCredentialsHandler sch = new ShopifyCredentialsHandler();
            test = sch.shopifyCredentialsHandler();
        }
        else if (newShoppingCart.equals("Bigcommerce")) {
        BigcommerceCredentialsHandler bch = new BigcommerceCredentialsHandler();
        test = bch.bigcommerceCredentialsHandler()
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("This method works with Shopify. Try to connect a Shopify store.");
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
    return test;
    // Here I need to return test (in case I choose "Shopify") or test2 (in case I choose "Bigcommerce"). How can I do that?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either declare `test` before your if statements or make multiple returns - one inside each if.

Answer (score 0):

As you have realised, the reason you can't access the "test" or "test2" variables where you want to make your return is because both of them are out of scope at that point.

You need to either declare a String variable up top (before your first if statement) where the scope of the variable would extend through the entire credentialsCollector() method, or use multiple returns, putting each return in the same scope as your "test" and "test2" variables.

Comment: this is a reasonable answer - but show a code snippet over describing the code snippet.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I just checked a result that @ritesh.garg proposed and it works great!

I didn't realize that I can create 1 test String and use returns of test String for each IF statement. I should be the best option, I believe.

Comment: No problem! Yeah that's the better of the two options.